# How to monitor the bandwidth with detailed files transfer information?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bandwidth, network-monitoring, multiple-instances

How can I know which file is transferring from instance to public internet? Is there any monitoring tools? When I am using bandwidth monitoring tool I have got whole output and input usage info but I needed detailed tracking of in/out files. How do I track them?

Comment: In general bandwidth monitoring tools monitor network devices, statistics, counters and flows. You need rely on application logs to drill down to the level of specific files.

Comment: what about outside of the application, if someone hack the instance how can we know which files are transferred ?

Comment: You don’t. Especially not when you use TLS to ensure transport encryption

Comment: sorry we know that if we use some log analyser like tools but i am not familiar with those tools